# Is it possible to download a podcast directly to an iPod Touch without jailbreaking?

Tags: ipod-touch, podcasts

Specifically with the iPod Touch that was released in September 2010, is it possible to download a podcast directly to the unit. The answers that I've found so far involve jailbreaking, which I'm not interested in doing.

I would like to avoid having to use my main computer at all for managing podcasts, if possible.

Comment: This depends a lot on what version of iOS you are running. Please specify software versions!

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a third party app like [PodCaster](http://podcaster.fm/).

Comment: +1 for the idea. For whatever reason, the 3rd party apps that I found all required jail breaking. This particular app, however, has some bad reviews that are concerning. Anyone know of more solid and polished apps that perform this function?

Comment: Yeah, that app is kinda marginal at best.

Answer (score 1):

On the iPhone which is more or less the same thing; in the iTunes application there is a podcast section under "More"

Comment: Does that mean that I can download a podcast directly to the iPod, or do I have to sync it from iTunes on my computer?

Comment: @Kyle Cronin: Aren't all iPod Touch models wifi-only?

Comment: @jdl Yes, sorry. u07ch mentioned his iPhone and I forgot the question was about iPod Touches.

Comment: Went to my local apple store on saturday; the iTunes application on them had the podcast section so if your podcast is in itunes you can download it without a computer.