# How can I download podcasts directly to my jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, podcasts

With a jailbroken iPhone 4.x, is there a way to download podcasts (about 60-100megs in size via an rss feed -- they are not in the iTunes store) directly to the phone without syncing?

Ideally, I'd like them to appear in the standard iTunes player on the phone with the other podcasts synced from my PC, but if this isn't possible, perhaps another app is available?

Similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/is-it-possible-to-download-a-podcast-directly-to-an-ipod-touch-without-jailbreaki), but I'm jailbroken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get **safari download manager** from cydia so that you can download it and **ifile** which lets you play it.

Comment: Also, for non jailbroken iphones -- Podcaster works great.  No file size restriction on 3g.

Answer (score 1):

Instacast for iPhone is a great podcast subscribing and listening app.

It is available in the iPhone app store so there is no need to jailbreak your phone.

It allows over the air syncing either from podcasts available via itunes or directly using a rss feed.

[Instacast](http://vemedio.com/products/instacast)